# navigator.getUserMedia function is undefined

Tags: javascript, navigator

```
Navigator.getUserMedia()
```

Can the navigator.getUserMedia function be undefined because the camera or access to the microphone is not granted access?

Comment: you might want to check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia) for this. Firstly, this feature is deprecated, secondly the return value of the function **is** `undefined`

Comment: is a deprecated on better use  [`MediaDevices`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia):

> This is a legacy method. Please use the newer
>   navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia() instead.

For example:

```
async function getMedia(constraints) {
  let stream = null;

  try {
    stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
    console.log('1')
    /* use the stream */
  } catch (err) {
    /* handle the error */
  }
}

getMedia({audio: true, video: true})
```

Source: [MediaDevices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly,** make sure you use `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` instead of `navigator.getUserMedia()`. The latter is deprecated.

**Secondly,** grabbing `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` on Chrome requires a **secure context**.
If the server is **js**-based, then you need to use **https** which then be used to access home page (e.g., index.html) instead of http.
https connection requires creating/using credentials (i.e., certificate and private key). The following code is given for the sake of demonstration:

```
// change key and cert if you have other ones you use with a different name
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('webrtcwwsocket-key.pem', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('webrtcwwsocket-cert.pem', 'utf8');
var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app)
```

If you are using **python**-based server, then you need to create ssl context as follows:

```
ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext()
ssl_context.load_cert_chain(cert_file_path, key_file_path)
```